# Is there a collection which is hash-based (Fast Retrieval), ordered, indexed and allows insertion?

Tags: collections, java-8

For my Project I need a Collection with following Features

a. Hash-based : Fast Retrieval because i may have to crawl through several thousand nodes at multiple levels

b. Ordered : All nodes have to maintain an insertion order. This is must

c. Indexed : I would need to frequently access first and last element of the collection without iterating

d. Fast Insertion : I may insert a node in between very frequently

The best fit from Java Collections was LinkedHashSet but only drawback is its not indexed. so i can't do something like `myCollection.last()`

The best i could do is

```
LinkedHashSet<Car> carList = new LinkedHashSet<Car>();
//Implemented hashCode() and equals()       
carList.add(new Car(new Engine("1234","V2"),"Indica","Tata"));
carList.add(new Car(new Engine("1235","V6"),"RS7","Audi"));
carList.add(new Car(new Engine("1236","V6"),"GT-R","Nissan"));
carList.add(new Car(new Engine("1237","V2"),"Indica","Tata"));
carList.add(new Car(new Engine("1237","V2"),"Indica","Tata"));
carList.add(new Car(new Engine("1238","V2"),"Indica","Tata"));
carList.add(new Car(new Engine("1239","V6"),"RS7","Audi"));
carList.add(new Car(new Engine("1240","V6"),"GT-R","Nissan"));

Car c = (Car)carList.toArray()[carList.size()-1];
System.out.println("Last : "+c); //Find last
```

But there is no good way to insert in a LinkedHashSet and this is where i have to reject LinkedHashSet.
I am open to other libraries only if they satisfy all my requirements mentioned above with a good performance and allow use of functional programming and Stream API.

Comment: A hash-based collection doesn't allow to "crawl through several thousand nodes". It allows checking fast if an element is contained in the collection. ArrayList is probably what you want.

Comment: "Crawl through..." ignore this part. It will be difficult to explain what i mean. Anyhow Arraylist has poor insertion performance. Cant use

Comment: Have you benchmarked it?

Comment: Not benchmarked but i know ArrayLists have poor insertion performance since they don't maintain pointers to previous and next elements as a result there is a shifting of elements in insertion which is expensive operation

Comment: And hardware is extremely fast at copying a chunk of memory. Benchmark it. Using pointers to previous and next elements would be much slower, because the elements wouldn't be collocated in memory, causing cache misses. Not to mention that you would need to iterate until the Nth element to insert a new one, which would be even slower. Don't make assumptions. Measure.

Comment: TreeMap comes Closest to my expectations

Comment: @Eugene I just referred to your article on Baeldung and my basic understanding from early college. ArrayList insertions are expensive as compared to some other ordered collections.

Comment: @RaghaveShukla let me ask you this: why do you think they are expensive?

Comment: The statement `Car c = (Car)carList.toArray()[carList.size()-1];` makes no sense. Besides that, don’t create artificial problems based on academic statements.

Comment: You can always just extend LinkedHashSet, and keep track of the last element added.

Comment: @Holger did you try compiling and running it

Comment: @Eugene i did not want to write too much so may be [this can help](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-ArrayList-take-more-time-to-insert-elements-in-the-beginning-than-LinkedList-in-Java)

Comment: @racraman thank you eventually i used TreeSet<T>. It worked well as it an ordered and sorted collection. I don't have to bother about maintaining the order as i have overridden Comparable. It also provides the methods like `first()` and `last()` to get the largest element. Since i have provided a comparable it would automatically insert the new element in the order as we expect.

Comment: So, it was an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) all the time. You say, you need “to maintain an insertion order”, but end up being fine with a sorted `TreeSet`. In the end, using a plain `ArrayList`, calling `sort` when truly needing it sorted, will still likely outperform the `TreeSet` solution…